# How to bind rsync to a specific interface?

Tags: networking, rsync

I have a lot of interfaces configured in my server, each of which connect to a specific nic card and have a separate routing table. These interfaces can be identified by "netstat -a" command.

Now, I want to execute the rsync command connecting only to specific interface. I have this requirement because each of the interfaces will go through a separate tunnel/path and I want a particular rsync command to sync files through a specified tunnel.

Specifically, I want a way to specify the interface name.

Thanks,
Mohan.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the address of the interface using `--address=x.x.x.x` on the command-line.

I don't think there is any way to specify the interface directly, but the `ip` command can tell you the address for an interface, so you could use something like this:

```
IP=$(ip -4 -br addr show eth0 | awk '{split($3,a,"/"); print a[1]}')
rsyncd ... --address=$IP
```

**Edit** For systems with the "real" iproute2 (anything not busybox-based, essentially), `ip` can produce JSON output which can be parsed a bit more sanely:

```
IP=$(ip -j -4 addr show wlo1 | jq .[0].addr_info[0].local)
rsyncd ... --address=$IP
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. But my concern is that the interface name is widely spread, and their addresses are not so spoken inside the software. So, are there no direct way to specify the interface name ? Say, I know the interface a is for the x business purpose so the software using x business should use interface a. But I can't guarentee the a's address remain same.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to specify the interface name directly.  You could always get the address for the interface, though - I'll update the answer to include it.

Comment: `ip -4 -br addr show eth0 | awk -F' +|/' '{print $3}'` Multiple separators can be specified to make awk command a little shorter

Comment: I've also added a version which uses the JSON output from `ip`, which can be parsed in more semantically-meaningful ways with `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

I've written this little perl script to turn interface names to addresses, save it as `iftoip` (or similar)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Interface::Simple;
use feature qw(say);

my $iface = shift;

my $if = IO::Interface::Simple->new($iface) or die "$!: $iface";
say $if->address;
exit 0;
```

You can do something similar with bash:

```
iftoip() {
  ip addr show $1 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1
}
```

just add the above 3 lines to `~/.bashrc` and start a new shell or `source ~/.bashrc`

Running it produces:

```
v@juno:~$ iftoip ens33
10.251.17.94
v@juno:~$ iftoip ens34
192.168.78.128
v@juno:~$ echo "IP=$(iftoip ens33)"
IP=10.251.17.94
v@juno:~$ iftoip ens35 #perl
No such device: ens35 at /home/v/bin/iftoip line 10.
```

or

```
v@juno:~$ iftoip ens35 #bash
Device "ens35" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been tried using 2 interfaces, with different subnets and worked.

```
rsync -avzP -e 'ssh -b 10.100.16.X' /var/tmp/ent1 10.100.16.X:/var/tmp/;

rsync -avzP -e 'ssh -b 10.100.20.X' /var/tmp/ent2 10.100.20.X:/var/tmp/ ;
```

Answer (score -1):

From client to server, over ssh use:

```
 rsync -avP -e 'ssh -b x.x.x.x' tmp/ server:tmp/
```